# External service detects failure after SQL trigger is called

Tags: sql, triggers

The database is running on SQL 2008R2.

An external service is updating the SVCLog table.

When a specific message is logged I would like to update a value in a different table.  When my trigger runs the service detects the insert into SVC-Log as having failed and attempts to insert the data a second time. Even though the trigger has executed successfully.

The Trigger Code is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateIndex6] on [dbo].[SVCLog] FOR INSERT AS BEGIN 
IF exists (SELECT '*' FROM INSERTED WHERE (INSERTED.LogEntry LIKE '%Work Item % Created'))

Begin
DECLARE @WorkID INT
DECLARE  @ProcessID INT
DECLARE @ProcessDescription NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT @WorkID = WorkID from inserted
SELECT @processid = ProcessId from WorkManagement where WorkID = @WorkID
SELECT @ProcessDescription = ProcessDescription from ActiveProcesses where  ProcessID = @ProcessID

IF @ProcessDescription like '%Falkland%' 
UPDATE WorkManagment SET Index6 = 'Falkland' WHERE WorkID = @WorkID;

IF @ProcessDescription like '%Canada%' 
UPDATE WorkManagment SET Index6 = 'Canada' WHERE WorkID = @WorkID;

END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one major problem in that your trigger doesn't work if someone inserts more than one row, or if someone inserts one row that matches more than one row in the table(s) you're comparing values with.  You could refactor it like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateIndex6] on [dbo].[SVCLog] FOR INSERT AS BEGIN 
IF exists (SELECT * FROM INSERTED WHERE (INSERTED.LogEntry LIKE '%Work Item % Created'))

Begin


UPDATE wm
SET Index6 = CASE WHEN ap.ProcessDescription LIKE '%Canada%' THEN 'Canada'
                  WHEN ap.ProcessDescription LIKE '%Falkland%' THEN 'Falkland'
                  ELSE Index6 END
FROM WorkManagement wm
INNER JOIN ActiveProcesses ap
ON ap.ProcessID = wm.ProcessID
INNER JOIN inserted i
ON wm.WorkID = i.WorkID

END
END
GO
```

That way, you're working with sets all the way through and won't get any nasty errors when you try to assign multiple results to a scalar variable (or miss rows you wanted to update because you did a `TOP 1` or somesuch).

This won't help you if your problem is deadlocks though.